# creating a dataframe out of nested loop data

Tags: python, data, data-cleaning

I have three parameter arrays ,Parameter1 = [6,7,8],Parameter2 = [11,12] and Parameter3 which can be calculated using Parameter1 and Parameter2. There is a mapping between parameter 1 and 2.

[image: this is the kind of mapping they have]

I want to create a dataframe in pandas which looks like :

[image]

There are multiple parameters and multiple rows so can not do manually. Can we do this using nested for loops

Comment: based on any formula you calculate parameter3 from p1 and p2? and I think it's possible to do it using excel functions?

Comment: i want to do that in python

Comment: ok, tell me the formula that calculates p3 from p1 and p2?

Comment: it can be anything, varies actually. you can consider it as a function of p1 and p2.

Comment: you can assume something like 0.5p1 + 0.3p2